# php file with mySql database to html using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

So I am trying to get create a HTML that uses javascript, PHP, and CSS. I am having issues figuring out how to get the PHP that pulls in my database to post on the website with a click of a button using a javascript function. I have tried to setup jquery and ajax but I just can't seem to get it to work. Everything is connected as it should be. I have googled and googled and tried many things so figured I would post and see if someone can help me out. If I post the PHP file into my HTML it works properly but I have multiple querys that I want associated with a button. If I can just get one button to work I should be good to go. Thank you.

**JS**

```
function mad_hosp(str) {
    if(str == 0){ 
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Error.";
        return;
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "madison_narc.php?",  true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

**Here are my buttons in HTML**

```
<div class="navbar">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <button onclick="main_hosp()"> 
                <a href=("#") class="button">Huntsville Hospital</a>
            </button>
            <button onclick="W&C_hosp()"> 
                <a href=("#") class="button">Womens and Childrens Hospital</a>
            </button>
            <button onclick="mad_hosp()">
                <a href=("#") class="button">Madison Hospital</a>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>


<p>Waiting for the location to be selected... <id="output"></p>
```

**PHP**

```
 <?php
 $sql = "SELECT
 currentinventoryaudit.MedId as MedID,
 (currentinventoryaudit.MedDescription) as MedicationDescription,
 sum(currentinventoryaudit.CurrentCount) as TotalOnHand,
 'MadisonNarcVault' as StationName

 FROM
 currentinventoryaudit

 where
 currentinventoryaudit.StationName like ('%CW101296%') and
 currentinventoryaudit.MedDescription not like ('key%') and
 currentinventoryaudit.MedDescription not like ('%zz-%') and
 currentinventoryaudit.MedDescription not like ('%alp%')

 group by
 2

 order by
 2 asc;";

 $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
 $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

 echo "<table>
    <tr>
    <th>MedID</th>
    <th>Medication Description</th>
    <th>Total On Hand</th>
    <th>Station Name</th>
    </tr>";
 if($resultCheck > 0) {
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo"<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['MedID']."</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row ['MedicationDescription']."</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row ['TotalOnHand']."</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row ['StationName']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
     }
     echo "</table>";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: jQuery makes that kind of AJAX and DOM manipulation a *lot* easier, by the way.

Comment: @AUTater: you will have to debug and give more details of the problem.  1- test your queries manually.  Do they work?  2- try your PHP page directly, does that return expected results?  3- check the values of $result, $resultCheck, does your while go through all the results?  In a sense, if your PHP ok so the problem is in the Ajax call or is the Ajax call ok and the problem is in PHP?

Comment: Yeah my php works. If I post the php script into the html it loads all the information like I want. I cant get the JS/ajax to work.

Comment: Your function mad_hosp expects a str argument, which you do not provide in the call.  The page is not called (based on the if (str == 0)).

Comment: And FYI, `W&C_hosp` is not a valid function name (the &).

Comment: do I just get rid of the str argument?

Comment: You could remove if from the function definition, you do not use it anywhere other then verify if it contains something.  Then nothing is done with it.

Comment: I removed it. Yeah doesnt seem like it made a difference

Comment: how does jQuery make it easier. Definitely open to making this easier before I start building more and more on this.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like valid markup.

```
<p>Waiting for the location to be selected... <id="output"></p>
```

Use this instead:

```
<div id="output">
    <p>Waiting for the location to be selected... </p>
</div>
```

`document.getElementById("output")` is looking for an element with an `id` attribute with a value of "output", not an `id` element.

Comment: Yeah not sure what I was thinking there. Thanks. Its corrected but still doesn't pull in the "output". JS still screwed up.

Comment: Ah, too bad. I thought that might be all there was to it. Do you know how to use the browser console to check for errors in your script?

Comment: Yeah I do. May have figured this out. for some reason my php file was in another folder let me rename the .php location in the 'get'

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\xampp\htdocs\Includes\madison_narc.php on line 23

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Includes\madison_narc.php on line 23

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Includes\madison_narc.php on line 24

Comment: Ah, so you did not define your connection to the database.  Typical `$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);`

Comment: I have the connection as a separate php file.

Comment: ok, if you still get the `undefined variable: conn` message, it could be that you have folder issues related to the include_once line.

Comment: So if I put the connection info in the php file that has the sql it connects properly. but doesnt connect when I call it.

Comment: <?php

include_once 'Includes/dbh.inc.php';

?>

Comment: It connects just fine to the database until I click the function(button) then gives me that undefined variable: conn message unless I put the connection in that php file. Maybe I had to do that to begin with, I dont know.